# android send mail with text body and subject

Tags: android

in my android app i give the option to send me a mail with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@domain.de");
                intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MY SUBJECT");

                try {
                    startActivity(intent.createChooser(intent, "SEND E-MAIL"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

It works but my email-address will not set automatically as receiver.
whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "email@domain.de");
```

with:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:email@domain.de"));
```